# FFmpeg: Get volume of frame or short timespan

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, volume

I want to make a program that automatically deletes frames from an mp4 when the volume for those frames is below a given threshold. How can I get the volume of each frame? Or, alternatively, the volume for time t in the video? Or for timespan dt?
(I'm not committed to FFmpeg yet, or even to the mp4 format, so feel free to suggest alternatives.)

Comment: Are you using the console app or direct API?